# Different between keyword "new" and "default" in create instance of class

Tags: c#, constructor

I have class like:

```
 class foo
    {
        public foo(string Text)
        {
        }
    }
```

After run this code for create instance of class the `obj1` set to `null`:

```
foo obj1 = default(foo);
```

And by blow code everything work fine:

```
foo obj2= new foo("bla bla");
```

I have 2 Question :

1. Whats happen to default contractor when run `default(foo);`?
2. Is `foo obj1 = default(foo);` equal the `foo obj1 = null`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `default` does not create an instance. It initialises a variable to the default value of `foo` (which for a class is null, and for an `int` is zero, etc).

Comment: @J.Steen Could I define a default value of a class?

Comment: @combo_ci: No, the rules are predefined by .NET. Classes default value is `null`, zero for numeric types and  for structs all members initialized to zero or `null`(depending on the type of member, if it's a reference-type or not). Rules are documented in [`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/default-keyword-in-generic-code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence default(T) only reserves the minimum memory required to hold a reference to, or instance of the type, it does not call any constructors.

- For primitive types like `int` and `bool` the value returned would be `0` or `false` respectively.
- For reference types (classes) the only reservation made is for the reference, which will be null
- For structs, the memory for the struct will be reserved according to the rules above, so reference fields will be initialized to `null`, even if they cannot normally be `null` because of a constructor! Value fields will have their default set (`0`, `false`, etc).
- For enum types, values will be initialized to their first (0 value) field unless you have manually assigned values to the enum labels, in which case the value will still be 0 and might be invalid.

Comment: "For enum types, values will be initialized to their first (0th) field." - not quite true - it will be zero; that may or may not be the value of the first (0th) field (I could have `enum Foo { A = 42, B = 12 }`, for example) - there might not even be an enum item with the value of zero

Comment: @MarcGravell: a quick test seems to prove you right and me wrong, thanks for teaching me something new today!

Answer (score 6):

Here is how [`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/default-keyword-in-generic-code) works:

> return `null` for
>   reference types and `zero` for numeric value types. For `structs`, it will
>   return each member of the `struct` initialized to `zero` or `null` depending
>   on whether they are value or reference types. For `nullable` value
>   types, default returns a `System.Nullable<T>`, which is initialized like
>   any `struct`.

[`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator) operator just creates new instance of the class and initialize properties/fields as it's written in the constructor.

> Used to create objects and invoke constructors.

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/default-keyword-in-generic-code), default sets the variable to its default value. That means nullable types will be set to null, numeric types set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

It does not call the constructor just initializes with the default value.
Keep in mind that it is also relevant for value types such as int, double and structs.
Another use case is default a generic type.
Each type has a predetermined default value which specified at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table